# JavaFX textfield: disabling cursor movement

Tags: javafx

I have created a custom component that extends TextField and allows for advanced editing of a specific type of string.

The arrow keys have been redefined to allow for specific behavior and should **not** trigger the default caret move however I do not seem to be able to stop it from moving. I have consumed() every type of event I could imagine, the caret will always move when hitting an arrow key.

Additionally when typing a new letter, it is first validated and if found invalid, the editing is undone. However the caret is always moved by one position whilst it shouldn't be moved when the letter you entered was invalid.

I currently have logic in place which will move the caret to the correct position so the control more or less works, the only problem is that the user sees the caret jumping around wildly as the code tries to counter the default moves.

On an interesting note: I have supplied the control with a contextual menu and when the contextual menu is shown, the caret stops its default moving (or it is suddenly fast enough so the user doesn't see it).

I am digging into the source code for the contextual menu to see if it sets or unsets something but I'm not seeing it. Any ideas how to stop the default caret movement of a textfield?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an event filter to stop left and right arrows from being processed by a node:

```
textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
      case LEFT:
      case RIGHT:
        keyEvent.consume();
    }
  }
});
```

It is kind of a strange thing to do though as the TextField will then no longer act the same way as a user might usually expect it to do so.

**Executable Sample**

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.beans.*;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldControl extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final TextField textField = new TextField("Phone: ");
    textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
          // block cursor control keys.
          case LEFT:
          case RIGHT:
          case UP:
          case DOWN:
          case PAGE_UP:
          case PAGE_DOWN:
          case HOME:
          case END:
            keyEvent.consume();

          // allow deletion and tab.
          case DELETE:
          case BACK_SPACE:
          case TAB:
            return;
        }

        // only allow digits and a few punctuation symbols to be entered.
        if (!"0123456789-() ".contains(keyEvent.getCharacter())) {
          keyEvent.consume();
        }
      }
    });

    textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
      @Override public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        // due to some weirdness JavaFX will auto select the text when the text field
        // receives focus, so instead deselect and position the caret at the end of the field.
        // Another weird thing is that a pulse must be run before the deselection or caret
        // positioning request occurs or it won't take effect, so a runnable seems to suffic to ensure that.
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override public void run() {
            textField.deselect();
            textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
          }
        });
      }
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox();
    layout.getChildren().setAll(new VBox(textField, new TextField()));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();

    textField.requestFocus();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
    private void handleKeyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
        //System.out.println(testing.getName());
        Scene scene = (Scene) logoHbox.getScene();
        System.out.println(ke.getCode());

        switch (ke.getCode()) {
            case LEFT:
               Integer previousKey = Integer.parseInt(((Control)ke.getSource()).getId()) - 1;
               System.out.println(previousKey);
               //System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ((Control)ke.getSource()).getId());
               if(previousKey == 0) {
                   return;
               }
               TextField tb = (TextField) scene.lookup("#"+previousKey);
               tb.requestFocus();
               System.out.println(tb.getText());
                break;

            case RIGHT:
               Integer nextKey = Integer.parseInt(((Control)ke.getSource()).getId()) + 1;
               System.out.println(nextKey);
               if(nextKey == 61) {
                   return;
               }
               //System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ((Control)ke.getSource()).getId());
               TextField right = (TextField) scene.lookup("#"+nextKey);
               right.requestFocus();
               //System.out.println(tb.getText());
                break;
            case DOWN:
               Integer DownKey = Integer.parseInt(((Control)ke.getSource()).getId()) + 10;
               System.out.println(DownKey);
               if(DownKey == 70) {
                   return;
               }
               //System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ((Control)ke.getSource()).getId());
               if(DownKey == 61) {
                   DownKey = 2;
               } else if(DownKey == 62) {
                   DownKey = 3;
               } else if(DownKey == 63) {
                   DownKey = 4;
               } else if(DownKey == 64) {
                   DownKey = 5;
               } else if(DownKey == 65) {
                   DownKey = 6;
               } else if(DownKey == 66) {
                   DownKey = 7;
               } else if(DownKey == 67) {
                   DownKey = 8;
               } else if(DownKey == 68) {
                   DownKey = 9;
               } else if(DownKey == 69) {
                   DownKey = 10;
               }
               TextField down = (TextField) scene.lookup("#"+DownKey);
               down.requestFocus();
               //System.out.println(tb.getText());
                break;
            case UP:
               Integer UpKey = Integer.parseInt(((Control)ke.getSource()).getId()) - 10;
               System.out.println(UpKey);
               //System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ((Control)ke.getSource()).getId());
               if(UpKey == -9) {
                   return;
               }
               if(UpKey == 0) {
                   UpKey = 59;
               } else if(UpKey == -1) {
                   UpKey = 58;
               } else if(UpKey == -2) {
                   UpKey = 57;
               } else if(UpKey == -3) {
                   UpKey = 56;
               } else if(UpKey == -4) {
                   UpKey = 55;
               } else if(UpKey == -5) {
                   UpKey = 54;
               } else if(UpKey == -6) {
                   UpKey = 53;
               } else if(UpKey == -7) {
                   UpKey = 52;
               } else if(UpKey == -8) {
                   UpKey = 51;
               }
               TextField up = (TextField) scene.lookup("#"+UpKey);
               up.requestFocus();
               //System.out.println(tb.getText());
                break;
            case F9:
               clearAll();
               break;
            case TAB:
               break;
            default:
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to implement this function is use the `caretPositionProperty()` method and add the listener. 
the code like follow:

```
this.textField.caretPositionProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            TextField textField = (TextField) property.getBean();
    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
        }
    });
```